# html and CSS to automatically Zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css

How we can automatically zoom out the Webpage when the browser window size is reduced and vice verse.
Such that the webpage fits to the browser window without scroll bars.

Comment: Your requirement is to create responsive design(cross device support). please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169499/on-minimizing-the-screen-the-table-should-shrink/35170290#35170290 for elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use bootstrap. Bootstrap helps in making your website responsive. You can try bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a container div or section, wich has a fixed size, and has a margin-left: 50% property. Then you have a fixed size space to put your things in. For blogs, this looks okay, those usually have that thin look, and a pretty wide margin on both sides. Even twitter uses this design.

This is good to make everything look uniform on different screen sizes between different computers and tablets, it's howecer not the best solution for mobile devices. To fix this issue, you could create a separate mobile subdomain (m.example.com).

To test responsivity, the best tool I found was chrome's built-in mobile emulator.